# jQuery tabs and AJAX : how to style the tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working with jQuery UI and the tabs widget.
As I am using those widgets in several places on the website I'm making, I take only the bare minimum from the default styling of jQuery UI, and make different styles for the different sets of tabs I have.

I usually have an architecture similar to this one:

```
<div id="smth-tabs">
    <ul id="smth-tabs-menu">
        <li> ....
    </ul>
    <div class="smth-tabs"> //First tab
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Now the problem is that, when I use AJAX to load the tabs (rather than having them in divs like in the example I gave), the div containing the tab is automatically generated, and has therefore only the classes of the widget ("ui-tabs-panel" and such).

Here is the code with which I am creating this AJAX based set of tabs:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#smth-tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Error" 
                );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is there option to pass to the tabs function to set a custom class on the tab container?
Or is there another way to do it?
Or must I simply resolve to adding the class to the loaded tab in case of success of the AJAX request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you style `#smth-tabs .ui-tabs-pane` or even `#smth-tabs > ul` and `#smth-tabs > div`?

Comment: I shall post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style `#smth-tabs .ui-tabs-pane` or even `#smth-tabs > ul` and `#smth-tabs > div`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your ajax return : 
`$( "#smth-tabs-1" ).addClass('yourClass') ;`

Indeed, your *n* tabs have id `#smth-tabs-n`

Comment: I'm going to go with the answer of GolezTrol because of its simplicity, however this answer is correct. I'll remember it for other similar cases. Thank you!